# Finding ActualWidth of a User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, actualwidth

I'm working on some layout stuff with XAML/C# and for certain reasons I am unable to use the `SizeToContent="Width"` option however I would like to simulate it in certain situations. I have a user control sitting inside of an expander and I would like to be able to get the ActualWidth of that user control so that when the expander is expanded I can increase the size of the GridColumn and window accordingly. Because the Expander starts off as `IsExpanded="False"` the ActualWidth property reads as 0.0. Is there any way I can get the ActualWidth of the user control as if it were fully visible and `SizeToContent="Width"` were in effect?

I've been trying desperately to figure out how to calculate this width without hardcoding the actual value. `DesiredSize.Width` and `RenderedSize.Width` also both return 0.0 when the expander is collapsed

Comment: If you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` can you just attach a `DataTrigger` and bind it to `ActualWidth` so when the binding is updated then so is your property? Entered as a comment because unfortunately dont have time to test but seems a legit option.

Comment: @ChrisW. I'll keep this suggestion in mind but I'm not sure that its the approach thats right for this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you run a `Measure` <s>& `Arrange`</s> pass, passing in an infinite `Size`, you'll be able to get the `DesiredSize`.

```
var infiniteSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
control.Measure(infiniteSize);
```

<s>`control.Arrange(new Rect(infiniteSize));`</s>

#### correction:

As mentioned in the comments, just calling `Measure()` with infinite `Size` does the trick; do not use `Arrange()`.

Comment: Throws System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot call arrange on a UIElement with infinite size or NaN

Comment: Jay, this worked fine without needing a call to Arrange(). After the Measure I was able to pull out the fully expanded width and height from the DesiredSize property